# jQuery: associate event to existing elements, and to new elements

Tags: jquery

I have a code to change an input value clicking on `+/-` symbols. When the value is `1`, the character `-` disappears.

My doubt: I would like the '-' also dissapears when the page is loaded. How to do that?

I have tried it, using `trigger` this way below, but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
 //...
}).trigger('change');
```

---

This is my code:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {

  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $('.substract').hide();
  }   
});


$('.add').on('click', function() {
    
    var old_value = parseInt($('input').val());
    $('input').val(old_value + 1).change();

})

$('.substract').on('click', function() {
    
    var old_value = parseInt($('input').val());
    $('input').val(old_value - 1).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="text" value="1">
<span class="add">+</span>
<span class="substract">-</span>
```

Comment: Why don't you just hide it with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend  you to use CSS

```
.substract { display:none; }
```

However using jQuery, just trigger the `change` event of `input`. Since you are using event delegation, you are bind event with `document` not with `input` thus `.trigger('change');` didn't worked.

```
 $('input').change();
```

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {

  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $('.substract').hide();
  }
});


$('.add').on('click', function() {

  var old_value = parseInt($('input').val());
  $('input').val(old_value + 1).change();

})

$('.substract').on('click', function() {

  var old_value = parseInt($('input').val());
  $('input').val(old_value - 1).change();
})

$('input').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1">
<span class="add">+</span>
<span class="substract">-</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a style on loading:

```
<span class="substract" style='display:none'>-</span>
```

Or if you prefear jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('.substract').hide();
}
```

Remember to wait the DOM ready to be sure that the element is loaded. I'll go for the first version and avoid that user could see the button and then see it disappearing after few seconds

Answer (score 0):

I'd hide the minus on load by putting

`<span class="substract" style="display: none;">-</span>`,

then add

```
if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $('.substract').hide();
}else{
    $('.substract').show(); // add this line
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dlaxotn2/2Lqu5bmf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Toggle a class:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
      $(this).nextAll('.substract').first().toggleClass('hidden', this.value == 1);
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="substract hidden">-</span>
```

CSS:

```
span.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

### DEMO